# Как реализовать удаление сущности, с фактическим её сохранением, но недоступностью для новых операций?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, архитектура, spring-data-jpa

Возникла архитектурная проблема.

Имеется сущность `Warehouse`. Я пытаюсь реализовать функционал удаления этой сущности. Проблема в том, что после удаления она должна продолжать существовать *(потому что она может быть важна для некоторых других сущностей)*, но не быть в то же время доступной для каких-то новых операций.

Например: грузовик привёз на склад товары. В программе создаётся сущность `Order`, которая ссылается на сущность `Warehouse`. После этого мы хотим удалить сущность `Warehouse`, потому что, допустим, этот склад расформировали, но нам всё так же важны сущности `Order`, поэтому мы не удаляем `Warehouse`, а делаем недоступным для формирования новых заказов.

**Warehouse**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouses")
public class Warehouse {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

**Order**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_id")
    private Warehouse warehouse;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;
}
```

Есть несколько вариантов решения этой задачи и ни один меня не устраивает:

#### Сделать в `Warehouse` поле `isActive` и проверять его перед каждым запросом

Это неплохой вариант, но он очень сложный, потому что `Warehouse` связан не только с `Order`, но и ещё с десятком сущностей. Сейчас я делаю простой JPQL-запрос:

```
SELECT w FROM Warehouse w WHERE w.id=:id
```

и его придётся модернизировать:

```
SELECT w FROM Warehouse w WHERE w.id=:id AND w.isActive=TRUE
```

причём надо понимать, что у меня таких запросов много и во всех очень разные условия.

#### Создать сущность `DeletedWarehouse`

Эта сущность ничем не будет отличаться от обычной сущности `Warehouse`, зато она не будет участвовать в запросах нормальных, ещё не удалённых сущностей. То есть в таком запросе:

```
SELECT w FROM Warehouse w WHERE w.id=:id
```

никаких удалённых складов мы не получим. Мне нравится этот вариант, но возникает вопрос - а какие поля делать, например, в сущности `Order`? Можно вот так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "deleted_warehouse_id")
    private DeletedWarehouse deletedWarehouse;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_id")
    private Warehouse warehouse;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;
}
```

Тут одно из полей всегда будет `null`: либо `warehouse`, либо `deletedWarehouse`. Это выглядит не очень адекватно.

#### Идеальный вариант

Идеальным вариантом было бы сделать сущности `ActiveWarehouse` и `DeletedWarehouse`, наследовать их от одного интерфейса, `Warehouse`:

**Warehouse**:

```
public interface Warehouse {

    int getId();

    String getName();
}
```

и, соответственно, этот интерфейс использовать в качестве поля в сущностях, которым нужен `Warehouse`. Например, вот так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "warehouse_id")
    private Warehouse warehouse; // это интерфейс

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;
}
```

Ну и как-то должна подгружаться нужная имплементация: `ActiveWarehouse` или `DeletedWarehouse`, в зависимости от того, какая из этих сущностей не `null`. Это был бы просто идеальный вариант, но я очень сомневаюсь, что что-то подобное возможно.

Comment: Думаю есть смысл подумать насчет колонки со статусом, но не как булеан поле, а как tinyint ну или что вы используете. Модернизировать текущий код немного под него и в будущем получите больше свободы. Например 0 - всё норм можно писать, 1 - можно читать и удалять (склад на этапе расформирования), но нельзя загружать и тд. Таким образом вы всегда сможете добавить дополнительные статусы, а в джаве сделать enum под это дело, в таблице в коментах добавить какой статус что делает.
ps возможно и другие варианты, от своей кастомной аннотации, до чего угодно

Comment: @wigravy но я не вижу особо разницы по сравнению с добавлением boolean поля. Да, свободы будет больше, но мне столько не надо, а по затратам на рефакторинг получится столько же

Comment: Даже при 300 sql запросах добавить строку WHERE w.status = 0 это очень быстро, пока не могу придумать более простого решения, которое бы не было костылем. С такими вопросами наверное лучше писать на англ форум, там количество джавистов гораздо больше

Comment: @wigravy да вопрос-то не в перфомансе, а скорее в простоте рефакторинга.

Comment: @wigravy ну и без костыля никак) ситуация уже такая